# Programatically fire a QMouseEvent and Keyboard Event given only global x,y coordinate

Tags: c++, winapi, qt, mouseevent, keyboard-events

on `MachineA` the `MouseMove` events are trapped from screen to `Machine B`'s `viewerWidget`. and `MouseClick` Events from `MachineB`'s widget are carried to `MachineA`'s Screen. `KeyboardEvent` of `MachineB` are carried to `MachineA`. I dont know on what widget this events triggered. What I know is the global x, y coordinates. even for `KeyboardEvents`.
My Questions are:

1. How to trap/fire the MouseMove or MouseClick Events from/to desktopWidget ?
2. how to trap/fire the Keyboard Events from/to desktopWidget ?

Comment: You should perhaps have created a new question. Completely changing your question means my answer (which correctly addressed your earlier question) no longer makes sense and even gets downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to this should do the trick.

```
QMouseEvent* event = new QMouseEvent( QEvent::MouseButtonPress, QPoint( x, y ), button, modifiers);
QApplication::postEvent( widget, event );
```

Comment: But I don't know on which object to fire it. What I know is just the global x, y coordinates. Nothing else.

Comment: What about our top most widget? Your main window?

Comment: Should I fire it on `desktopWidget` ? and How can I get MouseEvents and Kyeboard Events from DesktopWidget ? I need to fire it on Desktop. Not on a Specific Application window. whatever application sitting on that x,y coordinate will get that event.

Comment: Just so things are clear. Say we have machine A where the events happen. And you send them to machine B where you want to fire them.. 1) what is desktopWidget? 2) do you mean with your second question how to trap events on machine A?

Comment: It almost seems as if you're implementing some sort of RDP. I'm sorry, but I have no answer to your edits. My answer still holds for your original question, but you'll have to take it from there. Sorry.

Comment: @downvoter, why did you downvote my answer? It was the correct answer to the OPs original question, which was "How can I programatically fire a Mouse Event."